# passing parameter along with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to send the other parameter along with id?

**History controller**

```
 def edit
    @histories = History.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @histories = History.find(params[:id])
    @histories.projects_lkp_id = params[:projects_lkps_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @histories.update(history_params)
        format.html{ redirect_to histories_path(id: @histories.id), notice: "History updated successfully" }
      else
        format.html{ render 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

**History/view/index**

```
<% @histories.each do |d| %>
  <% d.pictures.each do |sAV|  %>
        <div><%= d.past %>
            <%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' ), edit_history_path(d) %></div>  
             <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-5'> <%=image_tag sAV.pic (:medium) %> </div>
    <% end %> 
    <% end %>
```

I need to send to the projects_lkps_id with this line  `<%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' ), edit_history_path(d) %></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' ), edit_history_path(d, projects_lkps_id: d.projects_lkp_id ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<%= link_to edit_history_path(d, projects_lkps_id: d.projects_lkp_id) do %>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs'></span>
<% end %>
```